# ResponsiveFilemanager fatal error

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

right now I am stuck. I am using TinyMCE on my page and I wanted to implement there ResponsiveFilemanager. So I did. Everything was fine but when I am trying to upload file the table is blank and only with error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function fix_get_params() in /web/htdocs2/nasehudebkacz/home/www/filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php on line 190

The code on that line is

```
    if (isset($_GET["descending"]))
{
    $descending = $_SESSION['RF']['descending'] = fix_get_params($_GET["descending"])==1;
}
else
{
    $descending = $_SESSION['RF']['descending'];    
}
```

Thanks for any help I am really desperate